# Event handling in react: in which cases do we need to use arrow function on event, and when do we just need to pass class method(function)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, events, react-hooks

Example:

1)

```html
<button onClick="{this.handleClick}">
 Click me
</button>
```

2. 

```html
<button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
```

Why right here we can't just pass a function? I mean WHY do we need here an arrow function.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>you clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Example 1 only works if you bound handleClick to the correct `this` value or if handleClick was defined as an arrow function. Binding methods is explained [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes). With functional components you won't have any of these complications and instead have others like [stale closures](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)

Comment: In the first example you pass a reference to the function, not executing the function by using `()`, so, that works as long as you do the binding in the constructor correctly. If you use `this.handleClick()` without an arrow function, the `handleClick` function will be executed with each render of the component, and not only when the button is clicked, which is not the desired result. With an arrow function it becomes a callback function that's called only when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't use an arrow function that function will get executed on render() regardless of a button click. That's why you set an arrow function, to prevent that behavior. In your case on every render, the counter will increase if you don't use the arrow function syntax

Comment: why is it happening so? i mean "...regardless of a button click."

Comment: By setting an arrow function, you are giving a reference to that function, not calling that function. If you just type handleClick(parm), when the render method gets executed, javascript will call that function. You can alternatively use this.handleClick.bind(parms)

Comment: I could not confirm this. No react does not call the function if you just pass its name without calling. Where did you get your source? @Dani

Answer (score 2):

You **can** use arrow function when you want to pass parameter to an event handler. Using arrow function is a choice, not necessity.

**Syntax:**

```
<button onClick={() => this.handleClick(id)} />
```

When you do not want to pass any parameter, you can pass **reference** of the function.

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>
```

***Important:***

Writing an arrow function means binding any function in render time.

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, id)} />
```

Arrow function is alternative of above syntax. So, You can choose to use arrow function. The difference is, Binding a function in render creates a new function each time the component renders. That means,, using arrow function or binding a function in render time can create performance issue in your application.

Follow this documentation for more details:
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html